# How to handle very small numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am writing a program in C++ which includes very small floating point numbers. So, I have used `double` to represent the numbers. But as the floating point numbers are multiplied in a loop, it results in the final product being 0. But I need to display the actual floating point number. How can I handle such numbers?

```
class myclass
{
private :
    double value;
}

double calculate(count)
{
    double  key=this->value;
    double prev_level=pow(2,level-1);
    if(key-prev_level >=0)
        key=key-prev_level;

    int index= (2* key) + table[row_num][pos];
    double num1=array_l1[index]; // array_l1 and array_l2 are of type double
    double num2=array_l2[index];

    std::pair<double,double> p = list[key].at(row_num);
    double data=p.first;
    prod1=num1 *data;

    data=p.second;
    prod2=num2 * data;

    return prod1+prod2;
}

void compute()
{

    double prod = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        myclass c1(count);
        myclass c2(count+1);
        double value= c1.calculate * c2.calculate();  

    }
}
```

I am not able to include all the code because of the size, but I hope this function can explain the problem I am facing. As the value of `count` increases, the value of `value` decreases. So for larger value of `count`, I get a 0.

How can I display the actual value of `value`?

Comment: The `num` does nothing. Try print your numbers using scientific notation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with small numbers and accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799439/dealing-with-small-numbers-and-accuracy)

Comment: What is `some_function()`? Why do you never use `num`? Please post the whole thing. "I am not able to write the full code because of the size" - don't worry, we can handle it, as can the textbox which will get a scrollbar.

Comment: And how do you inspect the value? `cout`? `printf`? something else? Again, you need to post all relevant code, not just a disjointed snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that you are using an output format that allows for scientific notation, not just a fixed number of digits after the decimal point.

If that still results in zero output, consider summing logarithms rather than multiplying the numbers directly.

If, for example, the objective is to compare ratios of products, you can complete the calculation in logarithms, without ever doing the exponentiation to return to the non-logarithm world.

If you just need to display the result, pick a large constant. Add the logarithm of the constant to the sum before doing the exponentiation, and include the constant in the display.

Answer (score 3):

The floating point types use a fixed size representation. This has two immediate implications:

1. In general values cannot be represented exactly but a rounded value is used instead.
2. The range of values is limited.

If you need more precision or a wider range you'll need a different representation. You might want to have a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).